# C#/.NET - Help, I have only three classes in my System.Web namespace

Tags: c#, system.web

I discovered the problem when I got a suggestion to use the System.Web.HttpUtility class for a certain task.

Looking at the documentation, I should have about 50 classes in System.Web, but I have only these:

```
AspNetHostingPermission
AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute 
AspNetHostingPermissionLevel
```

I make this assumption since they are the only ones showing up in intellisense, and I get build errors when trying to use any other classes than these three.

I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1, and in the reference dialog it says i have version 2.0 of the System.Web component.

I'm lost. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the three which are in the System Reference.

Have you added a reference to System.Web in your project?

Comment: Thank you!! Obviously I'm new to this :D